# Issue with Spring and Task Queue on Google App Engine (GAE/J). Tasks are running without wait

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, task-queue

I'm trying to migrate an app that I have done with servlets. I 
configured now Spring. The problem is that the enqueued tasks stopped 
working, they aren't waiting the amount of time setted up in the task 
properties with the *countdownMillis* method. Tasks are running without 
wait.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is only happening in the dev appserver. I can't imagine Spring would have any effect on task scheduling in production.